# How to fix div only inside another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a long page with scroll. And i want to fix a div only inside another div.

```
<div class="box" >
  <div class="inbox1">
    menu
  </div>
  <div class="inbox2">
    text
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

(See also this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujh30rLa/1/))

So, when I scroll a page, the green box should always be in view, but only inside the red box. When the red box scrolls up, the green box should stay in the red box and scroll up together with red box.

So I want to fix the green box inside the red box locally.

**UPD:** Looks like the only way is to use Jquery plugin stickyfill. Here is a good article http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042. Thanks to Paulie_D for position:sticky

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for but `position:sticky` seems to fulfil the requirement.

> So, when I scroll a page, the green box should always be in view, but only inside the red box. When the red box scrolls up, the green box should stay in the red box and scroll up together with red box.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.inbox1 {
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
.inbox2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inbox1">
    menu
  </div>
  <div class="inbox2">
    text
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[Position:sticky @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> The box position is calculated according to the normal flow (this is called the position in normal flow). Then the box is offset relative to its flow root and containing block and in all cases, including table elements, does not affect the position of any following boxes. When a box B is stickily positioned, the position of the following box is calculated as though B were not offset. The effect of ‘position: sticky’ on table elements is the same as for ‘position: relative’.

*Note: Browser support is not universal so you may need fallbacks such as JS polyfills.*

Comment: Interesting that this works in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.46 beta-m (64-bit) so the chart *may* be slightly out of date.

Comment: Doesn't work on mine (Version 54.0.2793.0 canary). Must be since it is 32-bit

Comment: I don't think I have the expermintal properties flag enabled but it's possible so that might be it too.

Answer (score -3):

I updated your fiddler in jsFiddle, please try it https://jsfiddle.net/ujh30rLa/3/

Following are the changes

```
body{

}
.inbox1{
  border:2px solid green;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  position:fixed
}
```

Comment: But it go out of the desired box https://jsfiddle.net/gr5Lk7ty/2/